# C# : FieldInfo.GetValue returns null

Tags: c#, reflection

I've a problem to retrieve my control f2 in the variable o via Reflection :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Form2 f2;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.Show();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Type controlType = this.GetType();
        FieldInfo f = controlType.GetField("f2", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        object o = f.GetValue(this); // o == null;
    }
}
```

Comment: My question is: why not access the value directly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because you create a local variable called `f2` in `button1_Click` but never set the class member `f2` to that new instance:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Creates a new variable called f2 that is local to the function
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();

    // To store the local instance to the class member, you need to un-comment
    // this.f2 = f2;        
    // or change the previous line of code to:
    // f2 = new Form2();

    // Show the local form
    f2.Show();
}
```

Therefore there is a null value in the class level `f2`.

I'm also assuming that you're just playing with reflection in this example. If this isn't strictly a test of reflection...you should just reference `this.f2` directly rather than through reflection.

Answer (score 1):

```
FieldInfo myf = typeof(Form1).GetField("f2");
   Console.Writeline(myf.GetValue(this));
```

Should work for ya!

Answer (score 0):

You aren't setting the value of the private field f2.  Instead you are creating a local variable called f2.  Instead of this code:

```
Form f2 = new Form();
```

use:

```
f2 = new Form();
```